# Виртуальная папка windows 10

Tags: windows, cmd, windows-10, minecraft

Я хочу установить Minecraft на диск E: и я пробовал сделать
это через

`mklink /D E:\Artem\.minecraft C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft`

Но у меня получилось наоборот: основная папка на диске С: а виртуальная на диске Е: Я пробовал сделать так

`mklink /D C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft E:\Artem\.minecraft`

но у меня ошибка: `The system cannot find the path specified.`

Comment: Ничего не понятно. mklink создает ссылку на папку, а не устанавливает программы, включая майнкрафт. Объясни понятнее, что ты хочешь сделать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Создай папку `E:\Artem\.minecraft`
2. Удали папку `C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft`
3. Создай ссылку `mklink /D C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft E:\Artem\.minecraft`

Теперь `C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft` - это ссылка на папку `E:\Artem\.minecraft`

При этом не гарантируется, что ты этим сможешь обмануть установщик майнкрафта.

Comment: получилось, я его обманул